# Loading print.css in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I load my `print.css` file in Rails 3.1?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you want the print css which applies to print media

The following should serve the purpose - 
stylesheet_link_tag "print", :media => "print"

Comment: I want to style the page for the printer, that's right. I'm not sure why   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %> <%= stylesheet_link_tag "print", :media => "print" %> turns into   <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/print.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/style.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/print.css?body=1" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> How to eliminate the line print.css for media="screen"

Comment: :media => print parameter would help you apply styles only to page you want to print.

Comment: Sure, but why does it insert <link href="/assets/print.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> into my file? Do you have an idea how to eliminate it?

Comment: do you have stylesheet_link_tag :all in the layout ? Cause it seems its loading all the styles from your asset folder and would have media screen attached to it by default.

Comment: No, I have only <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %> and <%= stylesheet_link_tag "print", :media => "print" %>

Comment: So how is the additional style.css loaded into the page ?

Comment: That's how: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>

Comment: I am experiencing this too. I changed `stylesheet_link_tag "application"` to `stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "screen"` and I have `stylesheet_link_tag "print", :media => "print"`. This resolves the HTML output (i.e. `<link href="/assets/print.css?body=1" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` but still, the effects of the `print.css` affects all screen media types.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you take a look in the application.css document you would see :

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
* and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
* the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*= require_self
*= require_tree . 
*/
```

It means that application.css will be included (require_self) and also the others CSS in the stylesheets folder (require_tree .).

I'm a beginner in Rails so I cannot go further in the explanation!
Search any informations about require_self, require_tree and SASS language.

Comment: Take a look at this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css)