# Asset Pipeline: excluding an admin.css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I upgraded a Rails 3.0 app to Rails 3.1 which involved putting this

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

in the application.css file. However, there's an admin.css file that's now overriding the main app css file.

Is there a way to exclude the admin.css file from being included? In the admin section of the site I manually include the admin.css file but I need a way to exclude it from the user interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Similar question was asked earlier and you should check that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css).

Sprockets uses manifest files to determine which assets to include and serve. These manifest files contain directives — instructions that tell Sprockets which files to require in order to build a single CSS or JavaScript file. With these directives, Sprockets loads the files specified, processes them if necessary, concatenates them into one single file and then compresses them (if Rails.application.config.assets.compress is true). By serving one file rather than many, the load time of pages can be greatly reduced because the browser makes fewer requests.

You can have as many manifest files as you need. For example the admin.css and admin.js manifest could contain the JS and CSS files that are used for the admin section of the application.

In particular, you can specify individual files and they are compiled in the order specified.

Example and more details can be found in [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).

Thus, your new application.css would become:

```
/*
 *= require styles
 *= require layout
 */

/* Other styles */
```

Answer (score 104):

You can use the `stub` sprockets' directive in your manifest like this :

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= stub admin
*/
```

This will exclude `admin.css` and also **ALL** css required in it !!
So, if your `admin.css`'s manifest seems like this :

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*= require_self
*/
```

the `bootstrap.css` will also be excludes and no `require` could fixe this ! Take care of this ;)

Comment: This is much more succinct answer to the original question.

Comment: This answer is helpful although there's something I don't like about the pattern of "include everything _except_ X". Seems like it would be cleaner to say "in this context, include X, in this other context, include Y". See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42281440/199712) for what might be a better solution in some cases. Having said that, I can imagine situations where `stub` would be totally necessary in appropriate.

Comment: Can I use `stub` to exclude a directory? If yes how?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to have two directories in `app/assets/stylesheets`, for example, a `public` directory and an `admin` directory.

Then, in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`, you can change `require_tree .` to `require_tree ./public`.

You might have to do something similar on the admin side. I happen to be using the [Administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) gem which knows where to find its own assets.

Comment: For JS assets could be something similar or not? What do you suggest to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

soluction is add in config/assets.rb

```
#config/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile  += %w(*.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf *.gif *.png *.ico *.swf *.xap masonry.pkgd.min.js jquery.colorbox-min.js i18n/jquery.colorbox-pt-BR.js admin.css)
```

And Add in app/views/layouts/_adm_layout.html.erb

```
#app/views/layouts/_adm_layout.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```