# How to exclude path from application.css Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my tree

```
stylesheets/
admin/
    admin.scss
    bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
application.css.scss
categoria.css.scss
categories.css.scss
comments.css.scss
groups.css.scss
home.css.scss
ie.css.scss
images.css.scss
images.js.coffee
specs.css.scss
```

1 -> Is it possible (in application.css) to don`t load bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less?

My problem is..

my app have two layouts, one of then called admin, i would like to load bootstrap only in this layout, not for all application..

everyone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add all your file separately in your application.css.scss, without bootstrap_and_overrides, like this :

```
/**
 * application-print.css
 *
 *= require categoria
 *= require categories
 ...
 */
```

and include bootstrap_and_overrides separtely

you could place your files in a directory and use `require_tree ./normal/`