# Twitter Bootstrap and Rails: How to make some views responsive and others not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

According to the bootstrap docs

adding the following to your `<head>` makes your site responsive

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">`

In rails and the asset pipeline you declare your css file in application.css so the last line above is not required.

Im using the bootstrap-sass gem and the above line is achieved this line of code in the application.css file

`@include "bootstrap-responsive";`

It works!

But unfortunately this makes every view responsive.

I have a number of views such as my backbone app that I dont want to be responsive.

I thought about declaring the `<meta viewport...>` tag into a layout file that is only used for the those parts of my site that require responsive behavior.

This doesn't seem to work and despite some views not declaring this meta tag via their layout, they still become responsive.

Since I cant granularly control which css files get loaded in the asset pipeline I'm a bit stumped how to turn off and on this responsive behavior.

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css) for some good info.  It can be overwhelming, know, you don't have to do ALL of that... The key is: if you remove require tree (which will not add all files in directory) you need to manually add them in config/environments/production.rb with:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( application-all.css application-print.css application-ie.css )
```

Then you can use stylesheet_link_tags with no issues...

To make it more flexible I add this to my application head:

```
<%= yield :head if content_for?(:head) %>
```

and then all my views use:

```
<% content_for(:head) do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{params[:controller]}.#{params[:action]}" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "#{params[:controller]}.#{params[:action]}" %>
<% end %>
```