# How can I make JQuery as include file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Now, I have this JQuery in my application.html.erb
But I see this in every html of my web site. So I want to put this in `refresh_post.js`, which is created in `/assets/javascripts`

But as you know, application.html.erb calls all JavaScript file in the directory. Because I use many and putting this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

How can I call this JQuery only when user is logged in. and Where should I make `refresh_post.js` at so that it won't be loaded unless user is logged in?
The purpose of doing this is for SEO. I don't want to put JavaScript in HTML.

**views/application.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user %>
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            refreshPartialPost();
            setInterval(refreshPartialPost, 1000)
        });


        function refreshPartialPost() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/posts/refresh_partial",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "script",
          });
        }
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this for your `application` layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<% if current_user %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'refresh_post' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %> <= Won't this load all the js files in directory???

Comment: In a default generated project, yes, because it will have the line `require_tree .` in it, but you can remove that.

Comment: Then it won't load most of them anymore. Do I need to place something this one by one???<%= javascript_include_tag 'refresh_post' %>

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css), Even though this is for CSS same can be applied for js

HTH