# Page-specific CSS with Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I would like to test out two different interfaces for my Rails application.  Ideally, I'd like to have two separate css files, one associated with each interface (e.g., new_interface.css and old_interface.css).  I currently have two different partials for the interfaces, one called _new_interface.html.erb and one called _old_interface.html.erb.  If I'd like to invoke the correct css file when a particular view is loaded, how would I do this? For example, if I load _new_interface.html.erb, I want it to load the new_interface.css file and ignore the old_interface.css file.

My application.css:

```
/*
*= require_tree
*/
```

Comment: Please check this previous question, it's about JavaScript but the solution is the same for CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code

Comment: I ended up using this solution.  thanks for your response!

Comment: I answered this question here if you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243434/separate-css-folders-for-separate-rails-controllers/26246392#26246392

Answer (score 6):

This question seems to be aimed at what you need to do: [Using Rails 3.1 assets pipeline to conditionally use certain css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css)

In a nutshell, you need to reorganize your app/assets/stylesheet folder into some subdirectories and change your manifest files so that not *everything* gets bundled together at run time.

Then you can put some conditional logic in your view so that it loads the right css for the job.  The content_for tag is probably going to be useful here.  You could edit app/views/layouts/application.html.erb and include a line just after the other javascript <%= yield :view_specific_css %>.  Then in your view file you can use

```
<% content_for :view_specific_css do %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "whatever %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should keep them both as part of application.css and do the following

application.html.haml/erb

```
body{:class => @old_layout ? "old_layout" : "new_layout"}
```

Then when ever you are in an action that is off the old layout in your controller put

```
@old_layout = true
```

Then in your css files either prepend everything with body.old_layout or body.new_layout or use scss, a subset of sass, and rap your current css files like so

```
body.old_layout{
  #all your old layout css goes here, all but body statements of course
}

body.new_layout{
  #all your new layout css goes here, all but body statements of course
}
```

This way you keep things simple with one css file. And with a solution that easily allows you to switch over each controller action one at a time.

Comment: thanks for your response.  can you explain what this line means?
body{:class => @old_layout ? "old_layout" : "new_layout"}
Does it mean that it checks the value of old_layout and makes the body class old_layout if it's true and new_layout if it's false?

Comment: Yes thats about right. But remember it will also do new_layout if (at)old_layout is nil also, so you don't have to set (at)old_layout in your controller action when your dealing with a method thats using the new layout. Its also a nice way of marking out which methods still need to be upgraded because each one of them will contain (at)old_layout = true.