# RoR stylesheet layout view link. What does `:media => all` mean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, layout, view

I have:

```
<&= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

but I am adding a (completely) alternative layout for some of the views in my application, with separate stylesheets. I would like to link the existing layout to only some of the stylesheets, and add others. What do I need to change here?

Answer (score 1):

for this you can create new file in views/layout as similar to your `application.html.erb` 
for example  i am creating  `home.html.erb`.Link your all stylesheets and js files in that and finally just add that layout name in your required controller as `layout 'home'`

Comment: That's what I did, but I want to know what should I write in the stylesheet_link_tag line in the new layout and in the old one, so that they will each link to their own stylesheets

Comment: you just add your required stylesheets in your new lay out <%= stylesheet_link_tag('stylesheet1','stylesheet2', :media => "all") %>

Comment: Thank you. But should I leave `media=> all` there? wouldn't that call all the stylesheets including the other layout ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate manifest file and include those manifest file
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css) will help you how to do this

Comment: I currently have a controller render a different layout file, and I'm trying to have a separate layout. Is that possible as well?

Comment: Yes,it is you can in your layout suppose it's sigin lay out you can use signin manifest

Answer (score 0):

It specifies that your `application.css` should be loaded when the page is viewed in all media types. It's a CSS property, not a Rails property.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-sheets for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate layout for whole controller or for specific actions

For example:

in your controller:

```
layout :resolve_layout
 #controller code
 ...
def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when "new", "create", "wait_conformation"
      "customer_layout"    
    else
      "producer_layout"
    end
end
```

Here `customer_layout` & `producer_layout` are layout files.