# Conditionally include separate manifest files with asset-pipeline on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, asset-pipeline

I have installed [CodeSleeve asset-pipeline](https://github.com/codesleeve/asset-pipeline) to manage and minify assets for my project. As I understood, all the scripts and stylesheets are controlled from **manifest files** located at: `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` and `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

That is all great, but what if I want to load different assets for different page? For example admin side of the application.
This situation is also mentioned in [asset-pipeline documentation](https://github.com/codesleeve/asset-pipeline#can-i-do-conditional-includes) and recommended to use separate manifest files.

> For example, if your application is silo'ed into admin section and user section then it probably makes sense to have a separate manifest file for each section.

Sounds great, but question remains. How?
Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css) about asset-pipeline on Rails 3.1 and a somewhat complicated solution for such a obvious need, as is the need to include different assets in different sections of the application. 
I still tried to make sense of that solution, but this is about Rails, so I still have no idea where are the manfiest files added in Laravel version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I first went much longer and complex path, hacking the config array with Laravel Event listener. Got it working though until I turned on production environment, which broke my admin section styles. Now after all the hair-pulling came back to [asset-pipeline documentation](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline#parameters) and found the very simple solution which had been right in front of my eyes the whole time: All you have to do is add parameter to include tag, like this:

```
<?= javascript_include_tag('admin/application') ?>
```

This will point to folder `assets/admin` and look for `application.js` from that folder. Resulting html markup will be:

```
<script src="assets/admin/application.js" data-foo="bar"></script>
```

Same thing with stylesheets.

Comment: I have tried this approach and it is breaking my site. I had two folders under /app/assets called 'desktop' and 'mobile'. When I added a link to the manifests <?= javascript_include_tag('desktop/javascript/application') ?> everything just blew up.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean by "blew up". Please be more specific about what happens. Your description about what you did, seems to be correct.

Comment: It can no longer load assets.

Comment: @BernardNandwa Sorry but it's impossible to figure out your error without any information. Please provide error message or something. Check what your debug console says? Does html mark-up generate? Does JS files actually exist where they should?

Comment: When I made the changes to use separate manifests the css and js on the website broke and actually there were no errors logged. What I was attempting was exactly what your answer documented. I configured the application.js file and also for the application.css file just as the main application.js file to get everything in the tree. Cache cleared. Assets Cleaned. Nothing working. I am using the latest version of the asset manager for the 4.2 branch. Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML?
src="assets/desktop/javascript/application.js" ?
If so, does http://yourdomain.tld/assets/desktop/javascript/application.js exist? Do you have application.js file in desktop/javascript directory and it is a manifest file?